# PHP AJAX datagrid for updating multiple rows (like tagging)?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm in need of an AJAX solution for searching / filtering through one table (let's call it 'products'), selecting multiple rows or "all matching results", and tagging them with taxonomies from a different table.

I'm unable to find a solution already available, but I thought I'd ask all of you clever people for help. At least to point me in the right direction.

Which datagrid (datatable) solution should I choose? I know there are a number out there, but mainly for updating data in a single table.

Requirements:

- **Classify selected rows** ('tag', 'categorize', or what you will) or all rows matching the query (could be "select all", of course).
- **AJAX based**, using PHP with MySQL.
- Any Javascript library or standalone solution is ok.

The updated items should show the tags/categories in the rows.

If you can even point me in the right direction, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it will be really hard to find something that fits your requirements.

Reading your question with words like "datagrid" and "datatable" makes me suspect that you come from .NET's world, where you have grid components that will work directly with the info on your table. The only thing that i've seen that resembles that for the web is [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/).

I've found some [exemples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html) that you might want to see

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Actually, I've searched a lot for this, and the terms datagrid and datatable are based on what I've found on the web. I'll look into ExtJS and see how far I get with that.

Comment: ExtJS seems powerful, and may be the best library to base this on, unless there's one that fits this exactly. I wish there were demos or tutorials for this purpose. I'll mark this as the best answer since noone else has responded.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion I received was to use a framework like CodeIgniter with ExtJS, and I googled it to find a tutorial at http://superdit.com/2010/07/10/crud-using-codeigniter-and-extjs-grid-part-1/ - the site has a four part tutorial in the series. Perhaps it can be helpful for someone tackling a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be exactly what you are looking for:

http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/how-to-select-elements-in-a-grid/

Comment: A really nice feature, but only for fast selection of rows using the mouse. My issue was regarding updating multiple rows with categories (Inserts and Deletes many-to-many of relationships) and other taxonomies, not just row selection. I was fortunate enough to get help from someone with Ext expertise...